# Why can't I create a new tag in Mobile?

Tags: discussion, tags, mobile-web

When I was using the mobile version of an SE site I got prompted with the error:

> new tags cannot be created from the mobile site. The tag 'sometag' is new.

Why is this so?

Comment: I find I am often asking questions using the mobile sites (such as when I am playing video games away from my computer and I want to ask something on Gaming), and would love to be able to create new tags when needed. It is unfortunate that I can't do this.

Comment: You can, by choosing the full-site option.

Comment: Why are you creating a tag named [tag:sometag]?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal I am not - I obfuscated the tag I was trying to create since it is irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably because it's really easy to make a typo when using a mobile browser, and they don't want to clutter the tag-space with misspellings, so it's prompting you to recheck.

For legitimate cases, just edit the tag in later when you're not using a mobile browser or switch to the full-site version.

Comment: This is the case.  It's very rare that a new tag is intentionally and correctly created, and mobile device auto correct and difficulty typing makes it even more likely that tags are accidentally created.  We just disallowed it altogether accordingly.

Comment: @KevinMontrose so why not ask "are you sure?". I had a legitimate case happen to me, and had to go on my pc...

Comment: I'd prompt for a "type again" or something as well.

Comment: @yydl: That's what happens on the full site...

Answer (score 2):

I've read [waiwai's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109064/351462), but I still think the restriction for creating tags on mobile feels a bit arbitrary.

- You can make a tag by switching to the desktop version of the site
- Stack Exchange shows a warning prompt when making a new tag to confirm it was spelled correctly
- The rep requirement to make tags is fairly high, so we can assume they aren't new or inexperienced SE users

If a user has the required rep to create a tag, I don't think their choice of platform should act as a limitation.

Comment: I am pretty sure the warning prompt when creating a new tag was added after this question was posted. I agree it takes the "sting" away, and these days there's not much point in this restriction.