# Why can't mobile sites create tags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I create a new tag in Mobile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109063/why-cant-i-create-a-new-tag-in-mobile)

Trying to create tags on the mobile site is not allowed. Is this restriction due to some technical consideration? It sounds rather arbitrary. If its an arbitrary restriction, can we please have it lifted?