# Why can't we make tags on the mobile site?

Tags: feature-request, tags, mobile-web, tag-creation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I create a new tag in Mobile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109063/why-cant-i-create-a-new-tag-in-mobile)

In the process of making a question from my iPhone, I tried to add a non-existent tag. After submitting, I got the message that tags can't be made from the mobile site. Is there a reasoning to this?

It is possible to add them still. You just need to go to the full site, add it, wait for the AJAX to unfreeze the screen sometimes, submit, and go back to the mobile site.

Obviously, that is a pain. So is there anyone who can fix it?