# Revisit the decision not allowing to create tags from mobile

Tags: discussion, tags, mobile-web, responsive-design

You [can't create tags when using the mobile version of the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109063/295232); when you attempt to do so, you're greeted with the following error message:

> New tags cannot be created from the mobile site. The tag '[tag name]' is new.

This [*also* happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ0xz.png) when creating a tag when editing from the First Posts review queue on mobile, even though that isn't technically part of the [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web).

However, I was able to 'circumvent' this by switching to the new responsive site. This seems a little inconsequential: if not being on mobile is really that important, the check should be added to the responsive site as well (and perhaps trigger on certain User-Agent values); if it's not, it's better to remove that check altogether (it could take a while for the review pages to become fully responsive). I don't really have a preference, I just want the inconsistency to be resolved. Do you have any thoughts/arguments to prefer one option over the other?

Comment: Wasn't the whole point of having a full and a mobile site to remove features that had some performance impact an/or were hard to support. This whole responsiveness push is aimed at removing the difference between full and mobile as well. Not sure what you want fixed. I would suggest to deliver responsive design in 6 to 8 weeks and be done with the mobile view.

Comment: @rene that would work for me, but I fear that in that case, the review pages (which only have a non-responsive version) will still have that check if you're on mobile or not.